# Numeric representation of logs (or events) to treat with Neural Networks

Tags: neural-network, word2vec, one-hot-encoding

Is there a recommended way to represent logs or events (for example from unix systems or web servers) in order to be treated by a Neural Network?. It seems that it could be done by one-hot encoding methods or word2vec, but not sure if there are better options.